# Store data from txt file into lists of lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am trying to parse data from a text file. I want to store each of the 9 numbers in a separate list, making it a list of lists. Here's what I have, I am not quite sure how to go from here.

```
file = open("data.txt", 'r')
Result = [line.split(',') for line in file.readlines()]

print(Result)
```

Here is what the txt file looks like:

```
3 7 5 
0 4 2 
8 1 6 

2 6 3 
1 0 8 
5 4 7 

4 1 6 
0 8 7 
2 3 5 

7 2 6 
4 1 3 
8 0 5
```

This is my output:

```
[['3 7 5 \n'], ['0 4 2 \n'], ['8 1 6 \n'], ['\n'], ['2 6 3 \n'], ['1 0 8 \n'], ['5 4 7 \n'], ['\n'], ['4 1 6 \n'], ['0 8 7 \n'], ['2 3 5 \n'], ['\n'], ['7 2 6 \n'], ['4 1 3 \n'], ['8 0 5 \n'],['\n']]
```

Comment: Why are you splitting on `,` in a file with no commas?

Comment: What should I be split by? Could you help please

Comment: I am trying to get a list of lists having each of the set of 9 numbers in each list

Comment: Have you looked at the data in the file?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at it but I cannot figure out a way to parse it

Comment: But if you looked at it, you would have noticed there are no commas?  Correct?  If so, then you would have next tried to figure out what to split the records on?

Comment: Maybe splitting by a blank newline?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you [split()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) on space which is default

```
res=[line.split() for line in file.readlines() if line.strip()]
>>>res
[['3', '7', '5'], ['0', '4', '2'], ['8', '1', '6'], ['2', '6', '3'], ['1', '0', '8'], ['5', '4', '7'], ['4', '1', '6'], ['0', '8', '7'], ['2', '3', '5'], ['7', '2', '6'], ['4', '1', '3'], ['8', '0', '5']]
```

if you want in a list of list

```
res =[]
sub =[]
for line in file.readlines():
    if line.strip():
        sub.append(line.split())
    else:
        res.append(sub)
        sub=[]

>>>res
[[['3', '7', '5'], ['0', '4', '2'], ['8', '1', '6']], [['2', '6', '3'], ['1', '0', '8'], ['5', '4', '7']], [['4', '1', '6'], ['0', '8', '7'], ['2', '3', '5']]]
```

if you want all 9 numbers in in a single list, use [extend](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/extend.html) instead of [append](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/append.html)

```
res =[]
sub =[]
for line in file.readlines():
    if line.strip():
        sub.extend(line.split())
    else:
        res.append(sub)
        sub=[]
>>>res
[['3', '7', '5', '0', '4', '2', '8', '1', '6'], ['2', '6', '3', '1', '0', '8', '5', '4', '7'], ['4', '1', '6', '0', '8', '7', '2', '3', '5']]
```

if you want to convert all to integers convert using [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

```
sub.extend([int(x) for x in line.split()])
```

Comment: This does not meet what the OP asked for.

Comment: I already tried this. Each of the 9 numbers should be in a separate list, in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic.

```
        listoflists = []
        list = []
        file = open('data.txt', 'r')
        for line in file.readlines():
            for n in line:
                if (n!=" " and  n!="\n"):
                    list.append(n)
                if line == '\n':
                    listoflists.append(list)
                    list=[]
        print(listoflists)
```

Result
[['3', '7', '5', '0', '4', '2', '8', '1', '6'], ['2', '6', '3', '1', '0', '8', '5', '4', '7'], ['4', '1', '6', '0', '8', '7', '2', '3', '5']]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,you can define number of items for each list and pass it to chunks function

```
file = open("data.txt", 'r')
l = list(filter(None,file.read().splitlines()))
l = list(filter(None," ".join(l).split(' ')))

def chunks(li,n):
    for i in range(0,len(li),n):
            yield li[i:i+n]

out = list(chunks(l,9))
```

output

```
[['3', '7', '5', '0', '4', '2', '8', '1', '6'],
 ['2', '6', '3', '1', '0', '8', '5', '4', '7'],
 ['4', '1', '6', '0', '8', '7', '2', '3', '5'],
 ['7', '2', '6', '4', '1', '3', '8', '0', '5']]
```